# How many images I need to have more fluently animation(Actionscript);

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, actionscript, multiplication

I have an onEnterFrame event:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.errors.IOError;

    public class Ball extends MovieClip {

        private var images:Array;
        private var frames:Array;
        var i:int = 0;
        public function Ball(images:Array) {

            this.images = images
            frames = new Array();
            images.forEach(function(current){
                        trace(current);
                var loader:Loader = new Loader();
                loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadCompleted);
                loader.load(new URLRequest(current));
            });

        }

        private function onLoadCompleted(e:Event):void{
            frames.push(e.currentTarget.content);
            i++;
            if(i == images.length)
            {
                ready();
            }

        }

        private function ready():void{

            i = 0;
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

        }

        private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void{


            graphics.clear();
            var bitmapData:BitmapData = frames[i].bitmapData;
            graphics.beginBitmapFill(bitmapData, new Matrix(), false, true);
            graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
            graphics.endFill();
            i++;
            if(i == frames.length)
            {
                i = 0;

            }


        }

    }

}
```

this class is getting an array of images and then animates it, and this is my main class:

```
public class Test extends MovieClip {

        private var ball:Ball;
        public function Test()
        {
            var images:Array = new Array();
            for(var i:int = 1; i < 21; i++)
            {
                images.push('ball' + i.toString(10) + '.png');

            }
            ball = new Ball(images);
            addChild(ball);
        }

    }
```

so as you see I am passing an array of 20 images, so the question is how many images I need to make a good animation, not roughly, but smoothly, creating every time a new image like ball1.png, ball2.png, ball3.png, ball4.png - I need to move the ball pixel by pixed to make a good animation? or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your perception and device and what you want to visualize from your content. 
Please refer to this site:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/mupad/plot/INTRO_FramesAndTimeRange.html

Comment: or what is better to use the graphics built-in object and his functions or by creating images? i am new to this and i don't know how to do better, drawing circles and lines i will have to make graphics.clear() and in every method copy/paste the code to draw more and more movements of some person or stickman) or creating 30-50 images))

Comment: there are much to read =), can you give me a litle short answer than that?)

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would consider is the framerate. There is no point in having more images as your framerate.

Basically for a smooth animation 30 fps should be ok. Also if you consider this for mobile devices I think you should not go higher than 30fps in order to have a good performance.

Regarding the number of images and how to animate them, I suggest you have a look into this game tutorial (Hungry Hero)

http://www.hsharma.com/tutorials/starting-with-starling-ep-3-sprite-sheets/ 
http://www.hsharma.com/tutorials/starting-with-starling-ep-5-parallax-background/